# SAPUI5 TileContainer nested JSON data binding

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I want to bind the array "machines" which is nested in my model to a SAPUI5 sap.m.TileContainer.

```js
var data_main = {  
      "name":"1",
      "company":{  
         "money":100000,
         "name":"2",
         "departments":{  
            "marketing":{  
               "marketingActivities":[  

],
               "marketingModifier":0,
               "numberOfEmployees":1
            },
            "production":{  
               "output":14281.287062979532,
               "outputCoefficientOfEmployees":10,
               "machines":[  
                  {  
                     "priceForNextUpdate":0,
                     "effectOnOutput":200,
                     "level":1,
                     "price":0,
                     "name":"lauterTub",
                     "id":1,
                     "value":2000,
                     "costPerRound":100
                  },
                  {  
                     "priceForNextUpdate":0,
                     "effectOnOutput":500,
                     "level":1,
                     "price":0,
                     "name":"fermantingVat",
                     "id":2,
                     "value":5000,
                     "costPerRound":200
                  },
                  {  
                     "priceForNextUpdate":0,
                     "level":0,
                     "price":0,
                     "effectOnCapacity":0,
                     "name":"storage",
                     "id":3,
                     "value":0,
                     "costPerRound":0
                  },
                  {  
                     "priceForNextUpdate":0,
                     "effectOnQuality":0,
                     "level":0,
                     "price":0,
                     "name":"beerFilter",
                     "id":4,
                     "value":0,
                     "costPerRound":0
                  },
                  {  
                     "priceForNextUpdate":0,
                     "effectOnOutput":300,
                     "level":1,
                     "price":0,
                     "name":"brewingCopper",
                     "id":5,
                     "value":3000,
                     "costPerRound":200
                  },
                  {  
                     "priceForNextUpdate":0,
                     "effectOnOutput":200,
                     "level":1,
                     "price":0,
                     "name":"mashTub",
                     "id":6,
                     "value":2000,
                     "costPerRound":50
                  },
                  {  
                     "priceForNextUpdate":0,
                     "effectOnQuality":0,
                     "level":0,
                     "price":0,
                     "name":"whirlpool",
                     "id":7,
                     "value":0,
                     "costPerRound":0
                  },
                  {  
                     "priceForNextUpdate":0,
                     "effectOnOutput":100,
                     "level":1,
                     "price":0,
                     "name":"maltMill",
                     "id":8,
                     "value":1000,
                     "costPerRound":50
                  }
               ],
               "numberOfEmployees":2,
               "quality":0,
               "capacity":0
            },
            "procurement":{  
               "numberOfEmployees":1
            },
            "sales":{  
               "numberOfEmployees":2
            }
         },
         "numberOfEmployees":6
      },
      "publicData":{  
         "markt":"Beispieleigenschaft des Marktes"
      }
   }
 var model_main = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data_main);
 sap.ui.getCore().setModel(model_main, "main");
```

In my view:

```js
new sap.m.TileContainer("tilecontainer_production", {
 width: "55em",
 height: "35em",
 editable: true,
 allowAdd: true,
 tiles: {
     path: "main>/company/departments/production/machines",
     template:  new sap.m.CustomTile({...})
)};
```

But nothing works. I tried to bind it to

- main>/machines
- machines
- main>machines
- main>company/departments/production/machines
- main>/company/departments/production/machines/

but nothing works.

Thanks in advance, I am really stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
I've done a mistake.

This is the correct solution:

You missed the **/** within the path
Accessing the property within the model is done with "modelname">/ so **main>/**
 is the beginning of the binding path

```
main>/company/departments/production/machines
```

Best regards

Comment: This does not work. I want to have one tile for every object in the array machines.

Comment: Updated my answer. sorry for the mistake. But this will work definetly